# How can I delete the dictionary of global variables?

Tags: python, python-2.7

So I was playing with `globals()` and tried this:

```
del globals()
```

Out:

```
SyntaxError: can't delete function call
```

How can I delete the dictionary of global variables? Is it only accessible through a function call so that it's impossible to delete?

**Edit**: I am aware that it is a bad idea and I am not planning to use it. I just want to know if it is possible, and if not, I want to know why.

Comment: You have the wrong notion of del in python. del deletes references, not objects.

Comment: Why do you want to "delete the dictionary of global variables"? What do you mean to achieve?

Comment: @interjay: knowledge, nothing else :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deleting the reference to `globals()` won't remove the dict. You can clear the dict like this

```
globals().clear()
```

but heavens knows what use that is.

There are still a lot of ways to get around without globals()

eg

```
object = 0 .__class__.__mro__[1]
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you give some explanations about that last line?

Answer (score 3):

You can't delete the global scope but you *can* clear it:

```
x = 1

globals().clear()

x
#>>> Traceback (most recent call last):
#>>>   File "", line 21, in <module>
#>>> NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

One warning though: whatever you're trying to do is *the wrong thing*, and you should do something else.